# Which is more efficient, union a sum or sum a union

Tags: sql

Which is more efficient, A or B?

A)

```
select sum(qty * price) from 
(
 select qty, price from table_a
 union all
 select qty, price from table_b
)
```

B)

```
select sum(sales) from 
(
 select sum(qty * price) as sales from table_a
 union all
 select sum(qty * price) as sales from table_b
)
```

I would think B because there's less intermediate results.

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: It probably makes no difference with a smart optimizer. You're probably right in principle.

Comment: Thanks, shawnt00 5. I thought so too. Gordon Linoff provided a detailed explanation in case you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is probably more efficient to do the aggregation on each table first.  The reason is that the standard aggregation algorithms are (usually) `O(n log n)`.  In such a case, you can compare the expected time:

- Aggregation on n + m rows
- Aggregation on n rows, aggregation on m rows, aggregation on 2 rows

The second would typically be better performing because the aggregation algorithms scale super-linearly.

**But** -- and there is a big but here -- without a `GROUP BY`, the aggregation algorithm may (depending on the database) simply read the tables and accumulate the values.  In that case, the first has slightly less overhead.

**But but** some database materialize derived tables.  The overhead for materializing the intermediate result would be quite expensive.  In such databases the first would be much preferred.

Comment: Thank you for the informative explanation. The profiling tools of the database should tell me if the database is a "But but" database, correct?

Comment: @milop . . . In theory, you should be able to see this in the `explain` plan.